# How to properly install GO with paths and all?

Tags: go

I have installed GO, setup the paths but when i run a file i get this error:

```
error!! exec: "sqlboiler": executable file not found in $PATH
exec: "sqlboiler": executable file not found in $PATH
exec: "sqlboiler": executable file not found in $PATH
exit status 3
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: did you follow https://go.dev/doc/install ? if your program requires to call additional binaries (like `sqlboiler`), did you add them to $PATH as well ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The installation instructions are good, https://go.dev/doc/install. However, for me un Ubuntu 20.4 in wsl2, the suggested path for the binaries wasn't enough. Only `go` and `gofmt` are added to */usr/local/go/bin*.

I did add the below to my `.bashrc`, since go install puts the binaries in this location on my system.

```sh
export PATH="$HOME/go/bin:$PATH"
```

Note, that the path to the binaries may differ on your system, so you have to adjust it accordingly.

Any binary you install with go install that is added to this path will be available to your shell afterwards.

For example:

```sh
$ go install github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler/v4@latest
$ go install github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler/v4/drivers/sqlboiler-psql@latest

$ whereis sqlboiler
sqlboiler: /home/blue/go/bin/sqlboiler
```

Potentially, you also need some database packages to your system. I am not sure on this any more. For example, you could add some Postgres libs if you are using Postgres. You have to see if it works without.

```
apt-get install postgresql-client-common postgresql-client-12
```

Comment: Why is it that when i update my GOPATH and i refresh my terminal it disappears?

Comment: I dont know but GOPATH is kind of not important for this. GOPATH was a way to manage your projects in some way, before go mod.

Comment: It might be important to mention that GOPATH has a default value $HOME/go, especially for the case it's already set to some other value.

Comment: I have installed both your commands for sqlboiler but when i do whereis sqlboiler i get nothing

Comment: did you set the path as I have described? $HOME/go/bin and restart your shell?

Comment: Yes i did that.

Answer (score 0):

> How to properly install GO with paths and all?

1. Install Go with the installer (Windows) or archive (extract into `/usr/local` on Linux/Mac).
2. When installing from archive, manually add the directory path where the `go` binary is located (`/usr/local/go`) to `PATH`.
3. Set `GOPATH` to a directory path wherein to contain `bin`, `pkg` and `src` sub-directories.
4. Add `${GOPATH}/bin` to `PATH`.

> What is going wrong?

The program you are running is trying to run the executable `sqlboiler`, which cannot be found in any of the directories specified in `PATH`.